# link does not open from app in safari in iOS 9.0 but works in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios9, ios9.3

I know this question is answered for many same time of title or with different title.I am trying below code.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(videoURL)
```

This line of code works fine in iOS simulator 8.xx/9.xx and returns true. But When I am trying to run my code in iPhone 9.Xx(unfortunately don't have iOS 8.xx device) then this line

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(videoURL)
```

is giving false.

I thought ,since my url contain https:// so i tried changing it to http:// but still no luck.Is there any kind of entry requires in .plist file somewhere.I assume but don't know if thats how it should be done.Can you guys help me out in this.

Regards

Comment: whats your URL. Its working fine in my iPhone 9.3.3

Comment: i was try to open https://www.youtube.com/.I dont know if https and http would make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code on actual device iPhone iOS 9.3.3

```
let videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFY-NDAAgFo"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: videoURL)!)
```

It just opened safari with youtube video

For **http** we need to add a key in Info.plist nowadays since iOS 9

Just before your last **dict** write these lines in Info.plist viewed as Source code.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Alternatively you can add a new key and make it as a dictionary and add a Boolean field as shown in image

Comment: info.plist entry was already there in my project,And I have tried let videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFY-NDAAgFo"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: videoURL)!).still no luck UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: videoURL)!) is still giving false.But on sim its working.Any way thanks for replying

Comment: your url format is not fine.Just write `let videoURL = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFY-NDAAgFo`

Comment: And Info.plist is always there in every project. Whats new in that. I asked you to add Transport Security key. But that you will only be used if you are using http and not https

Comment: Just copy paste the same URL codes that I have written in answer and check on device

Comment: If it worked for you kindly tick as corrected as answer

Comment: here is my observation ,I tried making one simple app and have run that on 9.3.2 and 9.0.1 ,Its working on 9.3.2 but not working on 9.0.1.Though i believe there are not much changes in these iOS version.But if any pls let me know.

Comment: Currently I dont have any iOS 9.0.x version device or simulators. So I might not be the right person to answer that

Comment: thats not an issue dude, Atleast i have something working and I will try to figure out what going on here.Btw thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @ManishSingh I think this might help you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231581/safari-on-ios-9-2-1-9-3-wont-open-links  There are bugs in iOS 9.0.x version which apple has fixed them in later versions

Comment: See this thread too https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7239092?tstart=0

Comment: good suggestion @Rajan ,Its an issue with 9.0.1 which got fixed with 9.3.x

Comment: Googling always helps .

Answer (score 0):

> remember this from iOS 9 onwards you can use **SFSafariViewController**

import SafariServices

```
private func openMYUrl(url: NSURL) {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: url)
            svc.delegate = self
            self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

> NOTE: if you are not using this app will reject . in my case its
>   happen.

Comment: No, its not like that. The sdks like google sign in make a reason for rejection. I just submitted the app last month which has a textview with links of youtube and many other google sites. Apple never rejected and accepted   in first go. Depends what you are using. Generally the sdks nowadays use SafariController

Answer (score 0):

This is an apple bug for iOS 9.0.x which got fixed in iOS 9.3.x.I am pasting the link for someone who wants to refer this link for for more info.Thanks Rajan for your answer and suggestion

[Please go through this apple release note](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1842?locale=en_US)